# Excel display accompanying data from dropdown column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Sheet 1 I have the following list:

```
     A            B
1    Name         Age
2    Amanda       12
3    Bob          43
4    Jim          22
```

Using this I am able to make a dropdown list in Sheet 2 via Data -> Data Validation where I can add the names (Amanda, Bob, Jim) via dropdown.

What I do not know is how to add in the accompanying data, in this instance column B, their age.

In Sheet 2 I would like to show the age of each person I have selected via dropdown, and see it on the row next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a`VLookup` formula, so if Sheet2!D2 holds the name, then E2 could be

```
=VLookup(D2, Sheet1!$A:$B, 2, False)
```

Comment: ... Just the same answer?

Comment: Pretty much, I must have taken too long to type mine coz I'm on a tablet. Slight advantage of mine is that it looks up from the whole of columns A and B so if more names/ages are added on Sheet1 the formula on Sheet2 doesn't have to change to account for the extra entries.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's good practice. Although Excel is smart and won't loop the whole column unnecessarily but it will probably loop all rows in the `UsedRange` which can end up being a lot of unnecessary calcs

Comment: Fair comment, although I've not yet experienced a performance issue doing it this way. Also, often the range I am doing the lookup on is being over-written with new data (import from another data source), so can regularly expand or contract. With lots of lookups it can be hard to keep track of where formulae need editing after a data refresh.

Comment: If you want to use a dynamic lookup range, you should look at using a named ranges or use a proper table rather than using entire column references in a formula

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

A [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is all you need. Say you have the dropdown in cell A1 (on Sheet2)

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
```